# How to know if a router is suitable as an upgrade

Tags: router

When I had my router installed, it came with 2 boxes. The engineer said it was because a default router can't handle the amount of data with fibre, And that I *had* to use the one supplied. I don't know if this is true...

I'm on 35mb fibre in the UK with PlusNet,  the current router is Technicolor TG582n FTTC but there is another box, a Huawei Echolife HG612, which I guess is a fibre modem.

My own research shows its not adsl or adsl2. Searches for FFTC router doesn't suggest that's a real term. I guess I need to search for a cable router but, since that term is an old term I don't know how relevant the search results will be.

I think the router only needs to be 450MB. But I can't find anything which suggests that is accurate.

So, what are the key terms I'm supposed to search for in order to find a replacement? I'm guessing the following model will work but I have no way of verifying it.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B005G9C4C2/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?qid=1391720421&sr=8-3&pi=SL75

Comment: FWIW, FTTC normally stands for *Fibre to the cabinet*, a term used to describe the new rollout of high speed internet in the UK where fibre is laid to the BT cabinet and the last part to the property is through the regular phone line but a special modem is required. Out of this modem, though, you should have a regular ethernet connection that you can plug into any router you want.

Comment: That is what I was hoping @zelanix but the engineer made it clear that due to very high data rates only specialist routers will suffice...  I wonder if he was 'mistaken'

Comment: So out of interest, what is the speed of your broadband?

Comment: @zelanix I get 35mb, which although fast I didn't think was anything special these days.

Comment: Hmm, that is definitely a special router I think, but of course, you could always plug another router / switch / access point into it if you want. What is the model number on the other box and how is it connected?

Comment: I will find that out and post in about 10 hours time, I'm sorry I can't get the information now

Comment: The TG582n FTTC appears to be a custom version of the TG582n that lets it interact with the fibre box.  Why do you need to upgrade it?

Comment: Ok, well, I suspect that the Buffalo router would work, but without actually seeing your setup it's hard to say for sure. As a worst case solution, you could still use it as an access point and simply use the TG582n as a passthrough router (disabling wifi etc.).

Comment: @Paul, simply because the Wi-Fi signal is getting worse as time goes on...  it also appears to be a common complaint with the router (weak wifi range)

Comment: @zelanix, the fibre modem is a Huawei Echolife HG612

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the same modem that I had with my BT Infinity package. I think that you will be ok with the Buffalo router actually. Just copy the WAN configurations as closely as possible and connect the modem to the blue WAN port. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the existing router alone. If you want better WiFi, add a good access point (or router configured as an access point) to your existing setup. This will be much simpler.